# Why do I get "2010-01-01 00:00:00 +900" from "2010-12-31 15:00:00 +000"?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I have NSDate, it will be shown as below if I used `NSLog(@"%@", date.description);`

> 2010-12-31 15:00:00 +0000

it will be shown as if I used `NSLog(@"%@", [date descriptionWithLocale:[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]]);`

> Saturday, January 1, 2011 12:00:00 AM
>   Japan Standard Time

But it will be show as below if I used `NSLog(@"%@", [date formattedDateString]);`

> 2010-01-01 00:00:00 +0900

Where do I make mistake?

```
- (NSString *)formattedDateString {
    return [self formattedStringUsingFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
}

- (NSString *)formattedStringUsingFormat:(NSString *)dateFormat {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
    NSString *ret = [formatter stringFromDate:self];
    [formatter release];
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got what I need as below:

> -(NSString *)formattedDateString {
>   　　return [self formattedStringUsingFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
>   }

Comment: So what was the problem in the first place?

Comment: Uppercase "Y" gives the year that the *week* of that date starts in.  Lowercase "y" gives the year of the date itself.  See [Unicode Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Answer (score 1):

You have a subclass of NSDate, right? My only guess is that you made some mistake somewhere else in the override code, maybe when setting the time components of the date (so to speak) so that the description string or its source data was not updated correctly.

Edit: Oh you got it working, great. Couple of seconds too late. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Both `2010-01-01 00:00:00 +900` and `2010-12-31 15:00:00 +000` point to the same time.

**Edit**:
Both `2011-01-01 00:00:00 +900` and `2010-12-31 15:00:00 +000` point to the same time.

Do you happen to live at GMT+9 (let's say Tokyo)?

Comment: How so? Jan 1, 2011 might get confused with Dec31, 2010 by timezone, but this seems to be off by a year.

Comment: Don: you are right. I am blind :) There is a thin chance though that the OP did a typo on the title of the issue.

Comment: Yes, I am in Tokyo. I see like you said, 2011-01-01 00:00:00 +900 is the same as 2010-12-31 15:00:00 +000, but I got 2010-01-01 15:00:00 +000, this is my question.